# Substract date column in mysql from current date

Tags: mysql

i have a table

```
id    dates
1    2016-11-06
2    2016-11-07
3    2016-11-06
4    2016-11-09
5    2016-11-10
6    2016-11-06
7    2016-11-03
```

i want to create a seperate column `diff` which will tell me the difference of dates  from current date.

```
id    dates       diff
1    2016-11-06     31
2    2016-11-07     30
3    2016-11-06     31
4    2016-11-09     28
5    2016-11-10     27
6    2016-11-06     31
7    2016-11-03     34
```

so i tried this query

select id , dates , TIMEDIFF(dates,CURDATE()) as diff from tablename;

but getting different result.

```
id    dates       diff
1    2016-11-06    -744:00:00
2    2016-11-07    -720:00:00
3    2016-11-06    -744:00:00
4    2016-11-09    -672:00:00
5    2016-11-10    -648:00:00
6    2016-11-06    -744:00:00
```

and so on.
Is there any way to get diff in the format i wanted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [**`TIMESTAMPDIFF`**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff):

```
SELECT 
    id,
    dates,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, dates, CURDATE()) AS diff
FROM tablename;
```

[**SqlFiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e92b7a/3)